# Placing an image with its default size

Tags: html, background-image

I am new to Web Dev and I am currently learning HTML and CSS. I like to be sure that I can do 100% of the stuff I can before going on with the learning and I am stuck in something which may be too silly but I have been struggling for hours on this.

What I want to do is to add a picture to a website using CSS (background-image).

This is the code I use(I use CSS but I placed it inside HTML within  tag for the sake of the question).

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
       <style>
  .fml {
     position: relative;
      background-image: url("http://oi63.tinypic.com/z6be8.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
      min-height: 100px;
      width: 30%;
      border: 1px solid;
     }
    .txt {
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
     }
       </style>
      </head>
      <body>
         <div class="fml">
        <p class="txt">This is a random picture</p>
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now as you can see, the background picture is shown only a fraction because the height is set to 100 px. But what if I want the program to detect automatically the size of the image and to extend its borders until the picture is shown on its real size? What if I don't know the size of the picture?

EXTRA QUESTION: As you can see, even though the text position is "bottom:0, left:0" it is not on bottom left, it's a little higher, why is that? Thank you for your answers!

PS: sorry for the indentation, I am in a hurry so I don't have time to indent the code in here properly. Thank you again for your answer!

Comment: If you mean you want the `div` to use the background image’s size as its own size, then it’s not possible. The only way for an element to have an intrinsic size based on the size of an image is to use the `img` element. On the other hand, if you want to have the background image fully shown in your div, you could consider the `cover` or `contain` values for `background-size`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I figured that using   img   element, the picture is fully shown without the need to specify any attribute. Unfortunately it's not possible to add a paragraph within the   img   element because it's a self-closing tag so it can't have children, therefore it is impossible to add a text on an image using   img tag   (using absolute position). Anyway, thank you for your answer, at least I know that it's not possible so I can go on learning new stuff.

Comment: Enclose the `img` in a `div`, set to `display: inline-block` and `position: relative`. Set the text to `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background of the whole webpage you want to use the body tag. Instead of calling your div id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      body {
          position: relative;
          background-image: url("http://oi63.tinypic.com/z6be8.jpg");
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          border: 1px solid;
    }

    .txt {
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fml">
        <p class="txt">This is a random picture</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```